# How can I place the links in the middle and the search at the end?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am trying to make a collapsible navbar where the search should align to the end and the links into the middle.

However I am unable to achieve it, I have tried all the justify examples, the relative outer and absolute inner classes but then it goes outside into the yellow which is outside the navbar space.

I am unsure what I need to do here to make this work.

[image: what it looks like, element selected]

As seen in the above my intention was to bring the search bar all the way to the end of the blue before the purple and align the links in the middle and leave the logo as is.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark p-0 b-0 m-0">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" href="#">
            <img class="d-inline-block align-top" src="" alt="Site Logo" height="26">
        </a>

        <button type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" class="navbar-toggler" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expand="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation" aria-expanded="true">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div id="navbarNav" style="" class="navbar-collapse collapse show">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill p-0 b-0 m-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">VIDEOS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">CATEGORIES</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">ACTORS</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">LOG IN</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">SIGN UP</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <form class="form-outline justify-content-end">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input class="form-control bg-secondary border-0 shadow-none pt-1 mt-1 pb-1 mb-1" type="text" placeholder="Search" style="color: white;">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary pt-1 mt-1 pb-1 mb-1">
                        <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add the `.flex-grow-1 justify-content-center` to the `.nav`

- `.flex-grow-1` will extend the nav width to the full remaining space.
- `.justify-content-center` makes the content of nav to the center.

or remove a `.nav-fill` on the `.nav` element if you don't want to fill space each of nav items

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if below code suits your requirement... I have added an inline-css and changed the container to container-fluid

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark p-0 b-0 m-0">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" href="#">
        <img class="d-inline-block align-top" src="" alt="Site Logo" height="26">
    </a>

    <button type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" class="navbar-toggler" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expand="false" aria-label="Toggle Navigation" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div id="navbarNav" class="navbar-collapse collapse show mx-auto" style="display:  flex; justify-content: space-evenly !important">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-fill p-0 b-0 m-0" style="justify-content:center;">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">VIDEOS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">CATEGORIES</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">ACTORS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">LOG IN</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">SIGN UP</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <form class="form-outline justify-content-end">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control bg-secondary border-0 shadow-none pt-1 mt-1 pb-1 mb-1" type="text" placeholder="Search" style="color: white;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary pt-1 mt-1 pb-1 mb-1">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
```